# What are the fundamental differences between a QA Analyst and a QA Tester role?

Tags: terminology, qa-role

I often see these titles used interchangeably and am wondering what subtle or major differentiators there are between these roles.

Comment: Yeah, they are used interchangeably. Having said it, you need to refer to the exact job description.

Comment: If you want to know what someone means when they use both of those terms, ask them.  We can't tell you what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think it all boils down to the word 'Tester' not being as catchy as it used to be. You'll find different terms searching for the same professional: Analyst, Engineer (though this one might infer some automation skills), Specialist, etc.

The role of either one of them is more or less the same depending on the company that is looking to hire. What you should keep in mind is the Job Description details: a title is meaningless without context.